# Saving a non user file with NeoVim, eg root owned /etc/pulse/default.pa

Tags: sudo

I am using NeoVim v0.4.3. 
This is the latest version available in repository.
I have an Arch build with the most up to date packages and kernel 5.6.4-arch1-1.

Occasionally I edit a file with nvim that I don't have permissions to edit.
I only realise this as I am about to save my work.

Recently I edited

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

with command

```
nvim /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

and no use of sudo.

This file has the following permissions

```
$ ls -la /etc/pulse/default.pa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4966 Jan 11 18:25 default.pa
```

So I did some googling and tried to save it with

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

and got this error

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; 
either use the -S option to read from standard 
input or configure an askpass helper

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

It also showed, on the highlighted bar, at the base of the screen, the following

```
/etc/pulse/default_2.pa [+][RO]
```

This did'nt work.

So I tried

```
:w !echo password | sudo -S tee %
```

It then displayed the following

```
:w !echo password | sudo -S tee %                                                                                      
[sudo] password for user:
W12: Warning: File "/etc/pulse/default.pa" has changed and the buffer was changed in Vim as well
See ":help W12" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

So I pressed `O` and nothing happened.
I then tried `:wq` and it complained the file was read only.

I then went through the process  again and this time pressed `L` and it showed

```
:w !echo password | sudo -S tee %
[sudo] password for user:
W12: Warning: File "/etc/pulse/default.pa" has changed and the buffer was changed in Vim as well
See ":help W12" for more info.
"/etc/pulse/default.pa" [readonly] 0L, 0C
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and nvim left me with a blank screen and an overwritten `etc/pulse/default.pa` file with nothing in it.

I've recovered the file but want to know how to `tee` the file down to disk when I open the file without the correct permissions.

I'm quite new to vim and think I got this working before but can't for the life of me remember how?

Comment: FWIW, I use this command: `exe 'w !sudo tee >/dev/null %:p:S' | setl nomod`, and I export this variable in my shell (from `~/.zshenv`): `export SUDO_ASKPASS='/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass'`. On Ubuntu this `x11-ssh-askpass` file is provided by the `ssh-askpass` package. I don't know what's the equivalent package on arch, nor where it's actually installed on an arch system.

Comment: Also consider using `sudoedit /etc/pulse/default.pa` (or `sudo -e /etc/pulse/default.pa`) which will make a temporary copy of the file for you to edit. Make sure your `$EDITOR` variable is set correctly so it uses nvim for editing the temporary file.

Comment: Thank you. I added this line to `.bashrc`,  `export SUDO_ASKPASS='/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass`
The `x11-ssh-askpass` package has same name on Arch.
I installed this package with `sudo pacman -S x11-ssh-askpass` & inserted this line into my  `~/.vimrc`,
`command W :execute ':silent w !sudo tee % > /dev/null' | :edit!`.
Now can I edit root owned files without losing data, saving with `:W` (capital W).
To make nvim more portable can I pass the password to sudo within nvim? 
I tried  `command W :execute ':silent w !echo password | sudo -S tee % > /dev/null' | :edit!` but this does not work.

Comment: @user938271 can you put this up as an answer please so I can press the tick button, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this `:W` command:

```
com -bar W exe 'w !sudo tee >/dev/null %:p:S' | setl nomod
```

Broken down:

```
"               ┌ write the buffer on the standard input of a shell command (`:h w_c`)
"               │ and execute the latter
"               │
"               │   ┌ raise the rights of the `tee(1)` process so that it can write in
"               │   │ a file owned by any user
"               ├─┐ │
com -bar W exe 'w !sudo tee >/dev/null %:p:S' | setl nomod
"                           ├────────┘ │ 
"                           │          └ but write in the current file
"                           │
"                           └ don't write in the terminal
```

You may also need to tell `sudo(8)` which helper program should be executed to read your password.

According to `man sudo`, there are 2 ways to do it.
You can either export the environment variable `SUDO_ASKPASS`, and assign it the path to the helper program; e.g.:

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS='/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass'
```

Here, the helper program is provided by the Ubuntu package `x11-ssh-askpass`; the name of the package, and the location of the file may differ on your OS.  Export the variable from an init file sourced by your shell (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshenv`, ...).

Or you can edit the `sudo.conf(5)` file, and include this directive inside:

```
Path askpass /usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass
```

---

For more info about the cause of the issue, see [this entry](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#-and-system-do-weird-things-with-interactive-processes) in the Neovim FAQ and the links it provides.

Answer (score 8):

[There’s a plugin for this](https://github.com/lambdalisue/suda.vim). The reason the old `:w !sudo tee %` doesn't work with Neovim has to do with the [refactoring following a client-server architecture](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1496#issuecomment-63695965), the team is working on a solution though that [hopefully will be shipped with 0.5](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1496#issuecomment-555181129)

Comment: I was sure I had `:w !sudo tee %` working somewhere before and thought it might have been in vim and not neovim, which you have confirmed. Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: I tried this plugin, and apparently it has a bug that prevents it from saving "large" files. The threshold for "large" is fairly low: it's failing for me on a file with 792 lines. https://github.com/lambdalisue/suda.vim/issues/5

Answer (score 3):

Try suda.vim : https://github.com/lambdalisue/suda.vim

In case you use vim plug, after plugging it (adding the line) with `Plug 'lambdalisue/suda.vim'` do a `:PlugInstall` and thereafter with `:SudaWrite` instead of the regular `:w` you will be prompted for a password and can save files as root which have been opened without root permission.

Answer (score 0):

I find a simple method to solve this problem.
Just type the password in the first line, then run the command `:w !sudo -S tee %`.

Thanks for the warning from D. Ben Knoble. I do not aware of this before. I do a test, it turns out that the password can be recovered by undo even had been closed if the persistent undo feature is on.

So, do try this method with cautious!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Beware that if you save the file with the password in it _and_ you are saving undo history, you could potentially expose the password to others. Restricting the permissions on undo files (or on undodir) helps, but is not failsafe.